# 'TypeError: is not a function' in NodeJS with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, ionic2

i have this problem in nodeJS with TypeScript. I have tested without and with **this.** :

> this.funktion2();
>              ^
>
> TypeError: this.funktion2 is not a function
>
> funktion1();      //case #two
>       ^
>
> ReferenceError: funktion1 is not defined

Here is my example code:

```
class App
{
  constructor()
  {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Hier 1');
      this.funktion2();
    }, 2500);

    //I have only one of this cases in use
    this.funktion1(); //case #one
    funktion1();      //case #two
  }

  function funktion1()
  {
    console.log('Funktion 1');
  }

    funktion2()
    {
      console.log('Funktion 2');
    }
}

new App();
```

How can i fix it or give s a workaround for it?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: If this is the actual example you're working on, then `funktion2` is missing the `function` keyword (should look similar to `function funktion1() {...}`). Then you'll be able to use `this.funktion1()` and `this.funktion2()` - but not `funktion1()` - Given you're using ES6

Comment: @AlexSzabó eh, the `function` keyword isn't mandatory in that context.

Comment: Hi no it's not the real code but i have the same problem in the real code. and i the an litle misstake. i have the problem in setTimeout(function(){...}, 2500). I can't call from there any function in my class.

Comment: @achmed24 did you try my example ? and read my explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with the following example

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Hier 1');
      this.funktion2();
    }, 2500);

    this.funktion1(); //case #one
  }

  funktion1() {
    console.log('Funktion 1');
  }

  funktion2(){
    console.log('Funktion 2');
  }
}

new App();
```

Another thing is, in the `setTimeout` if you use a function you can't have access to the class context `this`. The function create a new context so a new `this`

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('Hier 1');
  this.funktion2();
}, 2500);
```

To have access to the current context :

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('Hier 1');
  this.funktion2();
}, 2500);
```

Comment: Sorry i have overlook it. Thank you it s help me.

Comment: My pleasure, next time take your time to read what we trying to explain. thank's for the -1 ^^

Answer (score -1):

I have a litte misstake in the example

```
class App
{
  constructor()
  {
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Hier 1');
      //I have only one of this cases in use
      this.funktion2(); //case #one
      funktion2();      //case #two
    }, 2500);
    this.funktion1();// this work
  }

  function funktion1()
  {
    console.log('Funktion 1');
  }

    funktion2()
    {
      console.log('Funktion 2');
    }
}

new App();
```

But i have fund a workaround, when i want call **funktion2()**, not a nice but it work for my case:

```
class App
{
  constructor(b)
  {
    if(b)
    {
      this.funktion1();
      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Hier 1');
        new App(false);
      }, 2500);
    }
    else
    {
      this.funktion2();
    }

     //case #one
    //funktion1();      //case #two
  }

  funktion1()
  {
    console.log('Funktion 1');
  }

  funktion2()
  {
    console.log('Funktion 2');
  }
}

new App();
```

But if have anybody a better fix for it, i will be very happy.

Comment: Hey, if you read what i have explain before, there is your answer. What you wrote is an anti pattern work arround